# File Streams of Programming C++

Tags: c++, file, stream

When I copying the content of file Source.txt, which include only the word "Life", to another file Target.txt.
It only copy the "EI" not "Life".why?
The following

> Blockquote

is the code that i tried. is another way to copy one file content to another file. and also explain the following why it's happen?
Thanks in advance.
Great Confusion.

Source File include the following text:
Life
Copied Files from Source File is:
EI

```
char ch;
ifstream source("Source.txt");
ofstream target("Target.txt");
while(source.eof()==false)
{
 source.get(ch);
 target<<ch
```

Comment: Read [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is

```
char ch;
ifstream source("Source.txt");
ofstream target("Target.txt");
while(source.get(ch))
{
 target<<ch;
}
```

`eof` is only true *after* you read and it fails (because of eof). It's not generally true when you are at the end of file, i.e. if the *next* read will fail because of end of file. Because of this reason it's almost never correct to use `eof` in  a while loop condition.

[More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)